# Silverstripe: $LoginForm - Page not found on failed login

Tags: php, content-management-system, silverstripe

I have a member page. I want the content to only be visible when a user is logged in.

I considered hiding page content via Admin. However I want to have other forms, and content on this page when not logged in.

I have considered using the memberprofiles module, however I want to learn how to do this myself so I get a better understanding of Controllers, and Silverstripe Security.

Currently, the template looks like this:

```
<% if CurrentMember %>
    LOGGED IN
<% else %>
    You must login to proceed:
    $LoginForm
<% end_if%>
```

When NOT logged in, I am calling $LoginForm.

When I enter details incorrectly, the form redirects me to 'Page Not Found'. I have not extended the login form, or changed it in any way.

Member page URL when page not found:

`localhost:8888/site-name/members/login#MemberLoginForm_LoginForm_tab`

Not sure why the page isn't redirecting to Security/login.

**The desired outcome:**

- When a user enters details correctly, it redirects to the current page, but now the content is visible
- When a user enters details incorrectly, it redirects back to the login form and displays the relevant error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is in `MemberLoginForm` line 177:

```
    // Show the right tab on failed login
    $loginLink = Director::absoluteURL($this->controller->Link('login'));
```

It wants to send you to the `login/` action of the current controller (which `ContentController::LoginForm()` passes to it). I'm pretty sure that's a feature, not a bug, because chances are if you're using the login form outside of `Security`, you probably want to keep the user in that section rather than chucking them out to a separate template.

In any case, the easiest fix is just to add `login` as an `$allowed_action` on the controller that's showing the form.

```
class MyPage_Controller extends Page_Controller
{
  private static $allowed_actions = ['login'];
}
```

If you're displaying the form on every page, then just add that action to  `Page_Controller` so that all inheritors have it whitelisted.

Comment: Excellent. That worked perfectly. Thanks for the explanation.